# Center two elements vertically, and float left and right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to vertically align two divs in a parent div.

The vertical align is straightforward, but I am also trying float the divs, one left and one right.

Is this possible to do?

```css
.outer {
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.inner_right {
  background: blue;
  float: right;
}
.inner_left {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner_right">
    RIGHT MIDDLE
  </div>
  <div class="inner_left">
    LEFT MIDDLE
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xh8rbnmh/

Comment: Don't mix flex+floats. Don't mix floats+anything. Floats will crash your layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.outer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between; /* 1 */
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
}

.inner_right {
    order: 1;                       /* 2 */
    /* float: right; */             /* 3 */
    background: aqua;
}

.inner_left {
    /* float: left; */              /* 3 */
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner_right">RIGHT MIDDLE</div>
  <div class="inner_left">LEFT MIDDLE</div>
</div>
```

1. [methods for aligning flex items on main axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
2. [the flex `order` property can move elements around the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/3597276)
3. [floats are ignored in a flex formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-flexbox-1-20160301/#flex-containers)

Answer (score 1):

Simple. You need to put your left div first in the markup. Then simply add `margin: auto` to the right div.

**Note** that if you need to retain the original markup (with the right div first, then the left div), flexbox allows you to order the divs using the intuitive `order:` property on each div.

I've updated the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/v6facjnp/4/

Comment: Also, as @LordNeo noted, floats will not do anything when using flexbox, so you can get rid of those.

Comment: I can't change the markup, it has to be a pure css solution.

Comment: @renegade - I've updated my answer and fiddle based on the added requirement that the markup not change.

Comment: Either flex `auto` margins (like this answer) or `justify-content` (like my answer) can do the job. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is alternative solution not using flexbox - noticed that margin has to be height of element.

```
  .outer {
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
  position:relative;
 }
.inner_right {
 background: blue;
 position:absolute;
 right:0px;
 top:50%;
 margin-top: -18px;
 }

.inner_left {
 background: yellow;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:0px;
 margin-top: -18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First lets fix, some: left at the left, right at the right

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner_left">
   LEFT MIDDLE
  </div>
  <div class="inner_right">
    RIGHT MIDDLE
  </div>
</div>
```

Second: Flex makes the elements to behave like blocks, discarding the float property. So we use margins and justify

```
.outer {
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:flex-end; //Move all items to the right
}
.inner_right {
  background: blue;
}

.inner_left {
  background: yellow;
  margin-right:auto;//Move this to the left
}
```